Timeout before the position for partition could be determined in one topic in apache beam ReadFromKafka
I'm having a Google dataflow job, I'm using apache beam ReadFromKafka to consume topic messages. I'm consuming 4 topics. The pipeline used to work fine, after we added a new broker to our kafka cluster and triggered a rebalancing, the consumer started failing on one specific topic but successfully kept working for the
other 3 topics.
The error is: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition topic_name-0 could be determined 

Here is my code:
(
            pcoll
            | f"Read From Kafka {self.transf_label}"
            >> ReadFromKafka(
                consumer_config=self.kafka_consumer_config,
                topics=_topic_list,
                with_metadata=True,
            )
            | f"Extract KVT {self.transf_label}" >> Map(extract_key_value_topic)
            | f"Decode messages {self.transf_label}" >> ParDo(DecodeKafkaMessage())
        )

In the logs I can see
[Consumer clientId=consumer-group-dummy-4, groupId=consumer-group-dummy] Subscribed to partition(s): topic_name-0

But after few secs it fails with the timeout error, while continuously pulling messages of other topics
Here is the config:
{
        "bootstrap.servers": BROKERS,
        "security.protocol": SECURITY_PROTOCOL,
        "sasl.mechanism": SASL_MECHANISM,
        "group.id": "consumer-group-dummy",
        "session.timeout.ms": "60000",
        "sasl.jaas.config": f'org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="{SASL_USERNAME}" password="{SASL_PASSWORD}";',
        "auto.offset.reset": "latest",

    }

One thing to consider is our other Kafka consumer apps are not throwing any issue, this behavior is noticed only with the apache beam pipeline. Also when I tried to trigger locally a consumer with the same config and same consumer group using Kafka confluent library and simple python script, it seems to be working fine and pulling the messages.
I found this bug in Apache flink, can it be the same in the beam Kafka connector in Java?

My issue was the newly added brokers were not routed internally so the app was finding hard time reaching the broker that holds the partition that was causing the timeout.
Please note that this issue might be caused by several other factors, here are some of them that I encountered while doing the search:
Other factors:

This question already contains bunch of factors: stackoverflow

Stale metadata:
The controller node is in charge of updating topic metadata. If leadership of a topic partition has moved, a consumer will not be able to read it if it does not know which broker is the current leader for the partition. Stale metadata means the controller node isn’t doing its job and should be replaced.
zkCli.sh delete /controller to force a new controller elected
Cluster scaling/descaling:
details here
